# Applying forward fill on NaNs at the top of a column using df.fillna?

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

This is my data Frame

```
Id_Student  English History Mathmatic

1   66.0    NaN         80.0
2   NaN     66.0        NaN
3   NaN     NaN         NaN
4   55.0    94.0        94.0
```

I want to use this methode to fix missing value

```
mdf1 = mdf.fillna(method='ffill')
```

But it looks like if first value is NaN it's not helping much. First value under History column still NaN

```
Id_Student  English History Mathmatic

1       66.0        NaN      80.0
2       66.0       66.0      80.0
3       66.0       66.0      80.0
4       55.0       94.0      94.0
5       55.0       85.0      85.0
```

Any idea to fix this kind of issue 
Cheers mate

Comment: Any idea what you want to fill it with?

Comment: mdf.fillna(method='ffill') , Basically, this method takes the immediate value to fill missing value. I don't want to fill out missing value by mean or something else.  wanna use this one.df.fillna(method='ffill')

Comment: Obviously, `ffill` cannot fill something at the start, because there is nothing before it to carry forward. But you can use `bfill` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it is normal behaviour, because `ffill` replace `NaN` by forward filling and if no value in first row, then get `NaNs` only to first non NaN value.

You can use another [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) for replace `NaNs` which cannot be replaced by `ffill`:

```
mdf1 = mdf.ffill().fillna(0)
#same as
#mdf1 = mdf.fillna(method='ffill').fillna(0)
```

Same problem is with `bfill` (back filling) and `NaN`s values in last row, then is possible add `fillna` or another method:

```
print (mdf)
   Id_Student  English  History  Mathmatic
0           1     66.0      NaN        NaN
1           2      NaN     66.0        NaN
2           3      NaN      NaN        NaN
3           4     55.0     94.0       94.0
4           5      NaN     10.0        NaN
5           6      NaN      NaN       20.0

print (mdf.ffill())
   Id_Student  English  History  Mathmatic
0           1     66.0      NaN        NaN
1           2     66.0     66.0        NaN
2           3     66.0     66.0        NaN
3           4     55.0     94.0       94.0
4           5     55.0     10.0       94.0
5           6     55.0     10.0       20.0

print (mdf.bfill())
   Id_Student  English  History  Mathmatic
0           1     66.0     66.0       94.0
1           2     55.0     66.0       94.0
2           3     55.0     94.0       94.0
3           4     55.0     94.0       94.0
4           5      NaN     10.0       20.0
5           6      NaN      NaN       20.0
```

Replace by scalar all NaNs:

```
mdf1 = mdf.ffill().fillna(0)
print (mdf1)
   Id_Student  English  History  Mathmatic
0           1     66.0      0.0        0.0
1           2     66.0     66.0        0.0
2           3     66.0     66.0        0.0
3           4     55.0     94.0       94.0
4           5     55.0     10.0       94.0
5           6     55.0     10.0       20.0


mdf1 = mdf.bfill().fillna(0)
print (mdf1)
   Id_Student  English  History  Mathmatic
0           1     66.0     66.0       94.0
1           2     55.0     66.0       94.0
2           3     55.0     94.0       94.0
3           4     55.0     94.0       94.0
4           5      0.0     10.0       20.0
5           6      0.0      0.0       20.0
```

Replace by another method - if first `ffill`, then `bfill`:

```
mdf1 = mdf.ffill().bfill()
print (mdf1)
   Id_Student  English  History  Mathmatic
0           1     66.0     66.0       94.0
1           2     66.0     66.0       94.0
2           3     66.0     66.0       94.0
3           4     55.0     94.0       94.0
4           5     55.0     10.0       94.0
5           6     55.0     10.0       20.0


mdf1 = mdf.bfill().ffill()
print (mdf1)
   Id_Student  English  History  Mathmatic
0           1     66.0     66.0       94.0
1           2     55.0     66.0       94.0
2           3     55.0     94.0       94.0
3           4     55.0     94.0       94.0
4           5     55.0     10.0       20.0
5           6     55.0     10.0       20.0
```

Comment: OwO Jezrael, It's amazing solution with great explanation. Cheers mate